# Implementation Dependency in Maven Netbeans

Tags: maven, netbeans, dependencies

In an ordinary Netbeans project, I can specify a library as an implementation dependency so I can access its private packages.

However, in a Maven netbeans project, the menu for libraries (where I would set this) is not there, and the dependency system is different.  Is there an equivalent way in Maven to access private packages of a dependency?

Comment: What is a private package? Do you mean package private classes? Or some Java 9 mechanism to hide packages?

Comment: I believe it's a package private class.  Specifically I'm following [this tutorial](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/removing-menu-items-from-window-tabs) which specifies a workaround for an issue I'm facing -- it requires accessing org.netbeans.core.windows.actions.ActionsFactory, which when I try to access in code I get an error saying "Module dependency's private package referenced".  I could be misunderstanding the issue though.

Comment: (cont.) The issue being that in standard java netbeans I can [just set a dependency as an implementation dependency](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqImplementationDependency) to access things like that, but the dialogue menu for doing this in Netbeans doesn't exist for Maven projects.

Answer (score 1):

you want to read this section of the nbm-maven-plugin documentation. http://www.mojohaus.org/nbm-maven-plugin/manifest-mojo.html#moduleDependencies

An implementation dependency cannot be deduced from pom's dependencies section and you need to explicitly declare it as part of the plugin configuration.